# Lines on a smooth projective surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X \subset \mathbb P^n$ be a smooth, projective surface. Let $C$ be the hyperplane section of $X$. Let $D$ be a divisor on $X$ such that $C.D=1$. Then can we conclude that $D$ must be a line on $X$ and hence its arithmetic genus must be zero?

I do not see other than a line what else  it could be when $C.D=1$. Can we conclude this simply by definition or is there a short proof for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $D \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ is a curve such that $H \cdot D = 1$, where $H$ is the hyperplane class of $\mathbb{P}^n$ then $D$ is a line.

Comment: Does that mean if we assume $D$ is an non-zero effective divisor on $X$, then applying your answer (thinking $D \subset X \subset \mathbb P^n$), we get $D$ is a line on $X$ (or are you also assuming $D$ to be smooth?)?

Comment: I am not assuming that $D$ is smooth.

Comment: Just to make sure that I understand the situation correctly, for example if $n=3$ and the degree of the surface is $d$, then $C.D=1$ (with $D$ effective) will imply $D$ is a line in $\mathbb P^3$ and hence on $X$ and thus $D^2=2-d$, right? (and such a $D$ also need not be irreducible or reduced apriori, right?)

Comment: Any line is reduced and irreducible.